# SpringBoot Bean validation @NotEmpy is not Working

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I been trying to use spring `@NotEmpty` to make some input paramters in a REST api mandatory.

So far this is what I've achieved.

RestController

```
@RestController
public class ResourceController {

    @Autowired
    private GestionaDatosCrmService service;

    @PostMapping(path = Constantes.OBTENER_DATOS_CRM)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ObtenerDatosCrmResponse obtenerDatosCrm(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headerRequest,
            @Valid @RequestBody ObtenerDatosCrmRequest request, HttpServletResponse headerResponse) {
        return service.obtenerDatosCrm(headerRequest, request, headerResponse);
    }
}
```

Request Object

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

//import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class ObtenerDatosCrmRequest {

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a number")
    private String numSN;
    private String callID;

    public String getNumSN() {
        return numSN;
    }

    public void setNumSN(String numSN) {
        this.numSN = numSN;
    }

    public String getCallID() {
        return callID;
    }

    public void setCallID(String callID) {
        this.callID = callID;
    }
}
```

Note this important detail I'm using `javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty` for the `@NotEmpty` annotation but that doesn't work when I change to `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty` that is Deprecated the `@NotEmpty` kicks in and I get a 400 Bad request error when testing.

Im using spring boot 2.2.2.RELEASE, is there some know bug or issue about this?

Comment: It may just be that you are using hibernate's implementation of the validation specification. And it requires it's own annotation to work. That is most likely the culprit. Most likely not a bug, just how it works. From spring: "The basic configuration above will trigger Bean Validation to initialize using its default bootstrap mechanism. A JSR-303/JSR-349 provider, such as Hibernate Validator, is expected to be present in the classpath and will be detected automatically." see: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation

Comment: On my pom I've added dependencies for validation-api and hibernate-validator but none of these seem to work

Comment: Add request and response with body. You will recieve HTTP 400 Bad Request if @NotEmpty validation works and numSN field is empty

Comment: Try [@NotBlank](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/NotBlank.html) instead ..

Comment: @ShekharRai tried `@NotBlank` same thing doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I've had exactly the same issue and the solution that worked for me was to explicitly require a newer `hibernate-validator` version.

Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.1.2.Final'
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, dude! This dependency with `javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank` annotations in the POJO's fields and `@Valid` in controller Object works perfectly.